# socket.io won't emit messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am having troubles with `app.io.emit('admin', 'balls');` inside of the `games.js` file. The emits inside of the `io.on('connection'` output in the browser.

**/bin/www**

```
var app = require('../server'); //Which has references to games.js
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4001);
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'));

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('admin', { hello: 'received' });
  socket.on('admin', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
app.io = io;
```

**/app/controllers/admin/games.js**

```
// inside server.js -> require('games.js')(app);
module.exports = function(app) {
    //.....Other stuff
    app.io.emit('admin', 'balls');
});
```

**Html**

```
script(src="/js/socket.io-1.3.5.js")
script.
    $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('admin', function (data) {
            console.info(data);
        });
    })
```

**console output on page load in Chrome**

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/socket.io/?IO=3&transport=websocket&sid=QxjoI-yYF54oaQieAAAB' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
games:8 Object {hello: "received"}
```

I would like to be able to do emits whenever I want. Why isn't this working? Is it because I have to declare a reference to `io` with `app.io` and I am not starting the server with `('http')`?

Comment: How does /app/controllers/admin/games.js get `app`?

Comment: I've updated the question with how games.js is getting the reference to app. Its passed to it.

Comment: Won't games.js be initialized before any clients have connected and thus `app.io.emit()` does nothing because there are no connected clients at the time that games.js is initialized and `app.io.emit()` is called?

Comment: That is what I believe is going on. My solution was to init the io with `var server` then set a reference to `io` inside of `app` so that on ajax calls `app.io` is available? At least thats my logic atm :/ Console.logging `console.info(app.io);` also returns the `io` `object` :/ seems to work to me.

Comment: Holly smoke its working... I am using browserSync and was on the proxied port 4000, which was proxiing 4001. I moved to 4001 in the browser and it worked.. ashamed face!

Comment: You can either answer your own question if that would be a useful answer to the future StackOverflow community or you can just delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be something in my particular build that I over looked. The code was correct in how I was going about it.

I have `gulp` which I am then using `broswerSync` to proxy my instance so it can auto reload once everything has compliled.

My server is using port `4001` but the proxied site uses `4000` so when I navigated to `4001` everything was working as expected. No JS errors